# pgAdmin4 error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_validator'

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, archlinux, pgadmin-4

I'm trying to install `pgadmin4` on Arch Linux.
Here is what I did:

```sh
sudo pacman -S pgadmin4
```

Then I simply tried running `pgadmin4` and got the following error:

```
"An error occurred initialising the pgAdmin 4 server:\n\nFailed to launch the application server, server thread exiting."
```

Then, I tried running `pgAdmin4.py` directly:

```sh
sudo python3 /usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py
```

And I got an error with the following stacktrace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 35, in <module>
    import config
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/config.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pgadmin.utils import env, IS_WIN, fs_short_path
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
    from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, current_user
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_security/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .core import Security, RoleMixin, UserMixin, AnonymousUser, current_user
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_security/core.py", line 48, in <module>
    from .mail_util import MailUtil
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_security/mail_util.py", line 14, in <module>
    import email_validator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'email_validator'
```

I then tried to install `pip` in an attempt to install the missing module myself:

```sh
sudo pacman -S python-pip
```

Then:

```
pip install email_validator
```

However, the error remains. Should I modify my `PATH` variable? What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT**

So, after some help from the comments, and some more searching, I modified the `~/.config/pgadmin/pgadmin4.conf` file to have the following `PythonPath=/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages:/usr/lib/python3.9:/home/ddimitrov/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, which "resolved" this error but I was greeted with a brand new error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py", line 94, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/__init__.py", line 347, in create_app
    if not os.path.exists(SQLITE_PATH) or get_version() == -1:
  File "/usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin/setup/db_version.py", line 19, in get_version
    return version.value
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'
```

I tried since to reinstall `pgadmin4` multiple times, same issue. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you ensure that `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages` actually contains `email_validator` after your installation. You might got into some confusion with different python versions

Comment: the problem originates from flask_security: `from flask_security import Security, SQLAlchemyUserDatastore, current_user` You can try to run this import in your python console to narrow down the problem

Comment: I don't see the package in `/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, but I see it in `~/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages`, is this not correct? I ran `pip list -v` and that's the only package with a different directory.

Comment: By the way none of those directories are in my `PATH` variable? Should I add them there? I mean the `site-packages` ones.

Comment: there is an extra env variable `PYTHONPATH`. Can you check that? https://www.tutorialspoint.com/What-is-PYTHONPATH-environment-variable-in-Python

Comment: Hmm, It seems that this variable is not set. I didn't see anything about it on the Arch Wiki and the installation tutorials for python. Should I create it, and what should the value of it be? Did I miss something?

Comment: `~/.local/…` is not going to mean the same thing to sudo as it does to you. If pgadmin indeed runs runs on root (how about `postgres` user instead?) then you need to reason in terms of *their* PATH and HOME. And pythonpath

Comment: JL got a point. For this and other reasons, the pgadmin docs recommend a virtual python env: https://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgadmin-4-python/

Comment: @JLPeyret So when I do, `sudo -iu postgres python3 /usr/lib/pgadmin4/web/pgAdmin4.py`, I get the exact same error.

Comment: @Raphael but I didn't install `pgadmin4` through `pip`, but rather through `pacman`, I assumed it would set things up, didn't see anything in the installation about that. Sorry, I'm a bit confused.

Comment: mh, I would assume that too but it seems to fail at some point. You could try to install the package system wide `sudo pip install email_validator`

Comment: @Raphael, thanks that helped... I think? I mean I get another error now. `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'value'`, not sure what's going on. Thank you for your help, btw! Much appreciated!

Comment: your welcome :) does this new error also occur in `flask_security` or is it another library?

Comment: @Raphael Check my edit, I've included the new error and any progress that I've made.

Comment: that's a tricky one. pgadmin queries its internal sqlite database for its version but [Version.query.filter_by(name='ConfigDB')](https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/web/pgadmin/setup/db_version.py) returns  no rows. This case is not expected. Instead the query should either fail with an exception (which is handled) or return at least one row. Did you by any chance set this up with docker so that you could share the hole thing?

Comment: @Raphael At this point, I'll just assume that this version of `pgadmin4` on the arch repo is broken, I've spent way too much time on this. I hope someone would find this useful, if I manage to fix it, I'll update this question.

Comment: This belongs on Server Fault.

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't fix the specific issue, but it's too long to comment, but it will get you working:

You can run pgadmin4 via docker, and link it directly to the host network.

```
docker run -e 'PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=8080' \
           -e 'PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=user@domain.com' \
           -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=secret" \
           --network="host" \
           dpage/pgadmin4:latest
```

Then visit http://localhost:8080, login with `user@domain.com:secret`. You can now add servers like you might normally, just specify "localhost" as the host and your normal username (I think that's how arch configures access by default).

See also: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/container_deployment.html#examples

You can also look into configuring `pip install pgadmin4` and creating a `config.py` (perhaps in `/etc/pgadmin4`?) to set `SERVER_MODE=False`.

Really wish you could just go `pgadmin4 --desktop-mode`...

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a shot once I'm back on my Arch dev machine. Upvote from me

Answer (score 2):

Per Bastien Durel (bastiendurel) @ https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/70855
it looks like you'd need to downgrade python-flask and python-flask-security-too. They cannot be past 2.0 and 4.0 respectively.

I was having the same issue and downgraded each package and it's working now, but this may break any other packages that rely on the latest versions of python-flask and python-flask-security-too.

If you downgrade, you'd also need to update your /etc/pacman.conf to ignore both packages when updating.